# LU Matrix Solving

Tags: matlab

This is my current attempt at my own LU decomposition with pivoting. It seems to work with 2x2 and 3x3 matrices but nothing larger. I can't seem to find what is going wrong when tested against the built in lu.

```
function [L, U, P] = luFactor(A)

U = A;          %   U = upper triangular matrix
n = size(A);    %   n = number of rows in A
L = eye(n);     %   L = lower triangular matrix
P = eye(n);     %   P = initial pivot matrix

[n m]=size(A);
if n ~= m          %check if A is square
    error('Check dimensions of A')
end
for j=1:n-1
    [~,ind] = max(abs(U(j:n,j)));   %find what row largest value is in
    maxrow = U(ind+(j-1),1:n);      %save that rows that will be swapped
    swaprow = U(j,1:n);
    U(j,1:n)=maxrow;
    U(ind+(j-1),1:n)=swaprow;
    maxp = P(ind+(j-1),:);          %pivot P matrix to follow U
    swapp = P(j,:);
    P(j,:) = maxp;
    P(ind+(j-1),:) = swapp;

    for i=j:n-1
        L(i+1,j) = U(i+1,j)/U(j,j)          %determine coefficient to eliminate a variable
        U(i+1,:) = -(U(i+1,j)/U(j,j))*U(j,:)+U(i+1,:)      %multiply coeff by first row then subtract
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized I wasn't pivoting my L martix